# Elasticsearch group by and distinct

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I have a bunch of documents with the fields username and device_os as follows:

```
{ "username": "foo", "device_os": "Android", ....},
{ "username": "foo", "device_os": "iOS", ....},
{ "username": "bar", "device_os": "Android", ....},
{ "username": "baz", "device_os": "iOS", ....},
{ "username": "foo", "device_os": "iOS", ....}
```

I would like to get all distinct device_os by username as follows:

```
{ 
  "foo": ["Android", "iOS"],
  "bar": ["Android"],
  "baz": ["iOS"] 
}
```

What is the best way to do something like this in elasticsearch, specifically elasticsearch-py?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone gets here, the idea to solve this problem is simple: use a second level aggregation on the `usr_agg`, something like this:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "usr_agg": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "username.keyword"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "by_device_os": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "device_os.keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems not working, the nest aggs not found. `by_device_os` not found exception

Answer (score -1):

you can use "terms" aggregation in following manner

```
{
 "query": {
           "match_all": {}
          },
 "aggs":{
          "usr_agg":{
                     "terms": {"field": "username"}
                    }
        }
 }
```

For more [info](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

Comment: But how do I get the distinct device_os per user? This just has a terms aggregator for the username field

Comment: As of now I don't know if there is a way. One hack is you can use nested aggs to again aggregate devise_os